# Como filtrar un arreglo para encontrar sus iguales

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, map, nestjs

estoy haciendo uso de nodemailer para enviar correos electronicos, y dentro estoy adjuntado archivos pdf, para manejar los attachment y el limite de estos realizó ciertas validaciones.

**Contexto**

Tengo una validación que se encarga de dividir una matriz que lleva archivos en una más pequeña. Por ejemplo si tengo 20 archivos pero esos 20 archivos pesan más de un límite establecido de MB's realiza la validación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo otra matriz en donde tengo todos estos archivos sin filtrar, sin la validación, todos en una en donde devuelvo un ID (correlativo_solicitud) por decirlo así y el contenido (buffer) del archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces como yo necesitaba sacar de la matriz que divide la informacion del archivo (content) y sacar de la matriz sin dividir el ID (correlativo_solicitud) filtre esta matriz, en donde le dije que si el content de la matriz dividida es igual al content de la matriz B lo coloque en un nuevo arreglo con la información que necesito por cada vez que divida la matriz y me quedo algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora que ya tengo la info justo como la necesito, quiero que si el contenido de la matriz divida es igual al contenido de la nuevo matriz que cree (ans) por cada elemento de array quiero que me saque el fileName y los coloque en donde pertenecen

**Problema***

Mi problema es que cada vez que yo divida la matriz que lleva el contenido del attachment en una más pequeña, vaya y le asigne al correo un nuevo BODY que vaya en el cuerpo, por ejemplo imaginense que tengo 20 archivos por enviar y esos 20 archivos sobrepasan el limite de 25 MB. Si es asi, viene y va sacar esos attachments y los va ir convirtiendo en una matriz más pequeña que no sobrepase el tamaño

```
{
  EmailAttachment {
    filename: 'B-22-1-03 - Ana Lucia Márquez Hernández.pdf',
    content: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 34 0a 25 d3 eb e9 e1 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 2f 43 72 65 61 74 6f 72 20 28 43 68 72 6f 6d 69 75 6d 29 0a 2f 50 72 6f 64 ... 8208120 more bytes>,
    path: null,
    contentType: null,
    cid: null
  },
  EmailAttachment {
    filename: 'G-22-1-021 - Katerin Rivera.pdf',
    content: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 34 0a 25 d3 eb e9 e1 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 2f 43 72 65 61 74 6f 72 20 28 43 68 72 6f 6d 69 75 6d 29 0a 2f 50 72 6f 64 ... 277114 more bytes>,
    path: null,
    contentType: null,
    cid: null
  }
]
```

Entonces cuando ya las tenga divididas va ir y va comparar el contenido (buffer) y si igual a la matriz que trae la informacion del nuevo Body lo va colocar alli en donde pertenece

En mi lógica esa sería la mejor forma, pero en lugar de obtener lo que deseo solo obtengo un elemento del nuevo Body

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo me devuelve en el body lo que les marque en la imagen, cuando si en el attachment metio  ocho archivos, que me devuelva los ocho `fileName`

¿Ustedes creen que estoy manejando incorrectamente las matrices?. Les dejo el código, lo comente para que más o menos darme a entender un poquito

```
// numero en megas del attachment (archivo adjunto)
const totalSize: number = this.getSizeFromAttachments(attachments);
// obtener si es mayor
const chunkSplit = Math.floor(isNaN(totalSize) ? 1 : totalSize / this.LIMIT_ATTACHMENTS) + 1;
// funcion lodash para dividir la matriz
const attachmentsChunk: any[][] = _.chunk(attachments, chunkSplit);

 // dentro de los attachmente que se dividieron buscar content
            const result = attachment.map(element => this.getCantidad.find(y => element.content === y.content))
            // trae el nombre de los paciente y el correlativo de una consulta a solicitudes
            const aux = this.namePatient
            // nuevo arreglo
            const ans = []
            // por cada elemento del array que ya filtro
            result.forEach(ele => {
              // saca la llave del arreglo correlativo_solicitud
              const expected_key = ele["correlativo_solicitud"];
             // comprueba si la key anterior está presente en aux
              if (aux[expected_key]) {
                // crear una copia de algunos elementos en result
                const newItem = { ...ele };
                // Agregamos la nueva llave requerida, valor
                newItem["name_Patient"] = aux[expected_key]
                newItem["fileName"] = `Saludos se envía adjunto el resultado para la solicitud: ${expected_key}${aux[expected_key] ? ' - ' + aux[expected_key] : null}`
                // Agregamos el nuevo item a otro nuevo arreglo ans
                ans.push(newItem)
              }
            });

           console.log('newItem', ans);

            let newBody = '';
            // Por cada elemento del array saca el content del arreglo ans
            ans.forEach(element => {
              // por cada elemento del arreglo saca el content del attachment que divide los archivos
              attachment.forEach(item => {
                // si el conten del attachment == al del arreglo ans entonces extrae el nuevo cuerpo
                if (element.content === item.content) {
                  newBody = element.fileName;
                }
              });
            });

            // console.log('newBody', newBody);

            const link = `Estimado Usuario, la siguente solicitud le será enviado en diferentes correos. Este es el correo (${index + 1}/${attachmentsChunk?.length})`;
            const newContext = {
              getCurrent: link,
              newBody: newBody,
              ...context
            }

            return this.prepareEmail({
              para: to,
              asunto: `HOLAAA2 ${subject} (Correo ${index + 1}/${attachmentsChunk?.length - 1})`,
              plantilla: template,
              contexto: newContext,
            }, attachment);
          }
})
```

Se que el problema no esta tan facil, pero ya tengo una gran parte encaminada solo me gustaria si pueden aconsejar como puedo asignar el nuevo body segun la matriz dividida

Muchas gracias a todo el que se tome el tiempo de leerme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logré solucionarlo, solo realicé una validación sencilla accediendo a la nueva matriz que cree "ans" filtrandolo, y le dije que me filtrara los elementos de la raíz que incluyeran el mismo contenido y si es así lo meto en un nuevo array donde le paso el nuevo Body. Algo asi:

```
let newBody: any;
//Accediendo a la matriz que divide el attachment del correo
    const resultFilter = attachment.map(element => element.content)

            const newArr = [];
            ans.filter(element => {
              if (resultFilter.includes(element.content)) {
                newArr.push({
                  fileNameC: element.fileName
                })
              }
            })

            console.log('fileNameC', newArr);


            newBody = newArr.map(element => element.fileNameC)

            const link = `Estimado Usuario, la siguente solicitud le será enviado en diferentes correos. Este es el correo (${index + 1}/${attachmentsChunk?.length})`;

            const newContext = {
              getCurrent: link,
              newBody: newBody,
              ...context
            }
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]